# Скрыть части вебстраницы в WebView на kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Нужно загрузить веб страницу в WebView(в Fragment). Задача состоит в том, чтоб отобразить только часть страницы. Пытаюсь скрыть header(для начала), но всё равно подгружает страницу целиком. В официальной документации я не нашла ответа. Из найденных примеров на java получилось Это:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        webView = root.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview_home);
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  //enable javaScript
        webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())

        webView.loadUrl(url)
        return root
    }

    }
fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: URL) {
    webView.loadUrl(
        "javascript:(function() { " +
                "var head = document.getElementsById('h_area')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                "})()"
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю решить проблему можно предварительной загрузкой страницы и убиранием заголовка и футера:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(mUrl).get();
document.getElementsByClass("header-container").remove();
document.getElementsByClass("footer").remove();
WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//mWebView.loadData(document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8");
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
```

Comment: val document: org.jsoup.nodes.Document? = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
        document!!.getElementsByClass("header-container").remove()
        document!!.getElementsByClass("footer").remove()

        webView.getSettings()
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  //enable javaScript

        //mWebView.loadData(document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8");
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
        webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())

      webView.loadUrl(url)
        return root

не получилось: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: не понятно где у вас ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Сработало вот это

```
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        mWebView = root.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview_home)

                                                                    // подгон содержимого webView под размер экрана
        mWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        mWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true


        mWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true //enable javaScript


                                                                   // Set web view client

        mWebView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient(){
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
// Page loading finished
                view.loadUrl(
                    """javascript:(function f() {
document.getElementById('top_menu').style.display='none';
})()"""
                )
```