# Скрыть элемент сайта WebView Android

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

В общем смысл таков, допустим, на сайте есть тулбар и мне его надо скрыть, так как в приложении я создам свой бар и он будет находиться внизу. Как мне это сделать на Java? Есть код на Kotlin, но я не пишу на данном ЯП.

Сам вопрос и код на Kotlin: [Скрыть части вебстраницы в WebView на kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113151/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-webview-%d0%bd%d0%b0-kotlin)

Comment: вам перевести все на java нужно?

Comment: @Andrew , да. Если оно того стоит, ну код если реально рабочий, то можно.

Comment: код из ответа на java, или вам нужен код из вопроса?

Comment: @Andrew мне нужен код на java. Но я нашёл код на котлине. Если Вы можете предоставить код на java, этого вполне будет достаточно. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный Kotlin который я нашел в указанном вопросе, это код из самого вопроса:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        webView = root.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview_home);
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  //enable javaScript
        webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())

        webView.loadUrl(url)
        return root
    }

    }
fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: URL) {
    webView.loadUrl(
        "javascript:(function() { " +
                "var head = document.getElementsById('h_area')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                "})()"
    );
```

на java это будет выглядеть так:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater . inflate (R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        webView = root.findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview_home);
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  //enable javaScript
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient () {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
                webView.loadUrl(
                  "javascript:(function() { " +
                  "var head = document.getElementsById('h_area')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                  "})()"
);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            }
        });)

        webView.loadUrl(url)


        return rootView;
    }
```

я переместил функцию `onPageFinished` внутрь созданного клиента webview. Как-то так должно получиться в итоге я думаю.